# Getting image URI from Picasso cache

Tags: android, caching, picasso

1. Picasso load image from the web:
   `Picasso.with(context).load("http://dom.com/pic.png").into(imageView);`
2. After load i need to get the URI of stored in cache or memory image, such as:  `file:///data/data/com.dom.myapp/cache/pic-1689623235234.png` and put it into Extra for other `Activity`.

**How i can to get the image URI from Picasso cache or what another method to get it??**